# JavaFx ImageView binding image through fxml expression bindings

Tags: java, javafx, data-binding, expression, fxml

I know there are a lot of javafx tutorials out there. But 99% of them do not provide good fxml stuff.
Within fxml we can do databinding or "expression bindings" how it is called on javafx.

Binding an Image to the ImageView through expression binding works. But if the image changes, the actual displayed image won't change. How can I do this in javafx with less code-behind as possible.

The controller file

```
class MyController {
    private Image _imageA;
    private Image_ imageB;
    private Image_ image;

    public MyController(){
        _imageA = new Image(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("imageA.png"));
        _imageB = new Image(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("imageB.png"));
        _image = _imageA;
    }

    public getImage(){
        return _image;
    }

    public void mouseEnter(MouseEvent mouseEvent){
        _image = _imageA;
    }

    public void mouseLeave(MouseEvent mouseEvent){
        _image = _imageB;
    }
}
```

The fxml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<AnchorPane fx:id="_anchorPane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="868.0" prefWidth="1124.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/10.0.2-internal" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="MyController">

   <ImageView fx:id="_imgview" image="${controller.image}" onMouseEnter="#mouseEnter" onMouseExited="#mouseLeave"/>


</AnchorPane>
```

When the application starts the image gets displayed. But when the mouse cursor moves over the image then the getImage method gets invoked but the image wont change. 
Is there a way with minimum code-behind to solve this ?

What I do not want to do is this here

```
class MyController implements Initializable {
    //..other stuff
    @FXML
    private ImageView _imgview;
    SimpleObjectProperty<Image> _propertyImage = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();

    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
        _imageViewSettings.imageProperty().bind(_propertySettingsImage);
    }

    public void mouseEnter(MouseEvent mouseEvent){
        _imageProperty.setValue(_imageB);
    }

    public void mouseLeave(MouseEvent mouseEvent){
        _imageProperty.setValue(_imageA);
    }
}
```

With the TableView it is already possible to bind the data through an observable collection.
If the list content changes the tableview also changes. So here it works.

```
<TableView items="${controller.items}">
<!-- other stuff-->
 </TableView>

class TableController{

   private ObservableList<Integer> _list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

   ObservableList<Integer> getItems(){
        return _list;
   }
}
```

As I mentioned before, there are a lof of javafx examples. But just a few cover fxml. Most of the people
use

```
GridPane p = new GridPane();;
p.setAlignment(...);
p.setChildren(...);
```

But I thought that FXML was introduced to get rid of all this code-behind stuff like in WPF/XAML.
Long text short question. How do I bind the Image to the ImageView so that when the Image changes the ImageView will display the new image ?

kind regards,
Bob.

Comment: "What I do not want to do is this here...". Why not? That's the intended approach. If you want to bind to something, you have to make it `Observable` in the JavaFX sense, which means using a property or binding. But also, in your controller, you have a reference to the `ImageView`, so why not just call `setImage(...)` directly on it in the event handlers?

Comment: BTW I find it *really* difficult to read your code with all those superfluous underscores in the variable names. Can you stick to standard [Java naming conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java)?

Comment: While my answer shows an example of what (I believe) you want, keep in mind that not _everything_ can be accomplished directly in FXML. The dynamic parts of the view, and other more complicated view-related logic, will likely have to be defined in code, typically in the FXML controller. Depending on the architecture you use (e.g. MVC, MVP, MVVM, etc.), your controller can actually be quite complicated.

Answer (score 2):

You can only bind to something that can be observed (i.e. something that fires notifications when it changes its value). A standard Java reference will not do this, so simply binding to a regular value returned from a `get...()` method will not automatically update if that value changes.

So if you want to do this entirely with FXML expression bindings, so would need to use the JavaFX Property pattern, i.e.

```
class MyController implements Initializable {
    //..other stuff

    // you may not even need this if you use expression bindings uniquely:
    @FXML
    private ImageView imgview;

    private Image imageA;
    private Image imageB;

    public MyController(){
        imageA = new Image(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("imageA.png"));
        imageB = new Image(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("imageB.png"));
    }


    private final ObjectProperty<Image> image = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();

    public ObjectProperty<Image> imageProperty() {
        return image ;
    }

    public final Image getImage() {
        return imageProperty().get();
    }

    public final void setImage(Image image) {
        imageProperty().set(image);
    }

    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
        // ...
    }

    public void mouseEnter(MouseEvent mouseEvent){
        image.set(imageB);
    }

    public void mouseLeave(MouseEvent mouseEvent){
        image.set(imageA);
    }
}
```

Then

```xml
<ImageView fx:id="imgview" image="${controller.image}" onMouseEnter="#mouseEnter" onMouseExited="#mouseLeave"/>
```

will work as intended.

Alternatively, since your controller (which in the following scenario works more as a presenter) has a reference to the `ImageView`, you can do:

```xml
<ImageView fx:id="imgview" onMouseEnter="#mouseEnter" onMouseExited="#mouseLeave"/>
```

and

```
class MyController implements Initializable {
    //..other stuff

    @FXML
    private ImageView imgview;

    private Image imageA;
    private Image imageB;

    public MyController(){
        imageA = new Image(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("imageA.png"));
        imageB = new Image(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("imageB.png"));
    }

    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
        imageView.setImage(imageA);
    }


    public void mouseEnter(MouseEvent mouseEvent){
        imgview.setImage(imageB);
    }

    public void mouseLeave(MouseEvent mouseEvent){
        imageview.setImage(imageA);
    }
}
```

Finally, note that for this particular functionality, you can do all of this with CSS:

```xml
<ImageView fx:id="imgview" id="#my-image" />
```

and in the CSS file:

```
#my-image {
    -fx-image: url("@imageA.png");
}
#my-image:hover {
    -fx-image: url("@imageB.png");
}
```

and none of the controller code posted is needed (you may need to tweak the paths to the image here, as they will be relative to the CSS resource in this case).

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR**: To make the binding within the FXML file you need to make your image property observable (e.g. via an `ObjectProperty<Image>`).

---

There's nothing inherently special about FXML. It just defines a way to describe an object graph in XML syntax which is interpreted by an `FXMLLoader` and converted into normal Java objects. It uses relatively basic rules and the Java(FX)Bean conventions to accomplish this. More information can be found in the [Introduction to FXML](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html) document.

When you use expression bindings you are using the binding API of the JavaFX `Property` interface. In other words, when you have:

```xml
<ImageView image="${controller.image}"/>
```

It's basically the same as doing the following in code:

```java
public class FooController {

  private final ObjectProperty<Image> image = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(this, "image");
  // property-getter, getter, and setter omitted for brevity

  @FXML private ImageView imageView; // corresponding fx:id="imageView" in FXML file

  @FXML
  private void initialize() {
    // the "expression binding"
    imageView.imageProperty().bind(imageProperty());
  }
}
```

And that's where the problem in your example comes from. Your controller doesn't expose an *observable* image property; you only have a `getImage()` method. Since there's nothing that can be observed the `ImageView` cannot automatically update when the `Image` changes (i.e. there's nothing to bind to).

Here's an example where the controller exposes an `ObjectProperty<Image>`.

App.fxml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>

<BorderPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
            fx:controller="Controller" prefWidth="1000" prefHeight="650">

  <top>
    <Button text="Browse..." onAction="#handleBrowse" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER_RIGHT">
      <BorderPane.margin>
        <Insets topRightBottomLeft="5"/>
      </BorderPane.margin>
    </Button>
  </top>

  <center>
    <ScrollPane fitToHeight="true" fitToWidth="true" vbarPolicy="NEVER" hbarPolicy="NEVER" 
                pannable="true">
      <StackPane minWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity">
        <ImageView image="${controller.image}"/>
      </StackPane>
    </ScrollPane>
  </center>

</BorderPane>
```

Controller.java:

```java
import java.io.File;
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser.ExtensionFilter;
import javafx.stage.Window;

public class Controller {

  private final ObjectProperty<Image> image = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(this, "image");
  public final void setImage(Image image) { this.image.set(image); }
  public final Image getImage() { return image.get(); }
  public final ObjectProperty<Image> imageProperty() { return image; }

  @FXML
  private void handleBrowse(ActionEvent event) {
    event.consume();

    Window window = ((Button) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();

    FileChooser chooser = new FileChooser();
    chooser
        .getExtensionFilters()
        .addAll(new ExtensionFilter("Image Files", "*.png", "*.jpg", "*.jpeg", "*.gif"));
    File file = chooser.showOpenDialog(window);
    if (file != null) {
      setImage(new Image(file.toURI().toString()));
    }
  }
}
```

Main.java

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(Main.class.getResource("App.fxml"));
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
    primaryStage.show();
  }
}
```

---

As an aside, please follow [Java naming conventions](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html#s5-naming), at least when posting to a public forum. Those underscores (`_`) in your variable/field names are not conventional and make it harder for other Java programmers to understand your code.